# Solving and plotting an equation

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I would like to solve the following equation and make a log-log plot of $M$ against $\lambda$:

$$\bigg|\frac{2\lambda^{2}}{(4\pi)^{2}} \frac{m^{2}}{m_{h}^{2}} \left[\log\left(\frac{m_{h}^{2}}{m^{2}}\right) - \frac{7}{6} \right]\bigg| = 10^{-12}$$

What is wrong with the following code?

```
table = 
  Table[
    {Exp[M], λ /. 
       NSolve[
         (((2*(λ^2))/(4 *Pi)^(2)) *(1/Exp[2 M]) *[Log[Exp[2 M]] - (7/6)]) == 
           10^(-12), λ][[2]]}, 
    {M, -15, 15, 0.03}];

ListLogLogPlot[table]
```

Comment: In your code you use `square` brackets instead of `parentheses` for the `Log` term. Try this:
`table = Table[{Exp[M], \[Lambda] /. 
     NSolve[0.0023193043361 - (((2*(\[Lambda]^2))/(4 *Pi)^(2)) *(1/
             Exp[2 M]) *(Log[Exp[2 M]] - (7/6))) == 
        10^(-12), \[Lambda]][[2]]}, {M, -15, 15, 0.03}];
ListLogLogPlot[table]`

Comment: Your code doesn't correspond with the equation you presented in MathJaX.

Comment: why does it not?

Answer (score 1):

```
f[a_, m_] := Abs[2 a^2/(4 Pi m)^2 (Log[m^2] - 7/6)]
sol[j_] := {Exp[j], a} /. 
  NSolve[f[a, Exp[j]] == 10^-12 && a > 0, a][[1]]
tab = Table[sol[j], {j, -15, 15, 0.03}];
ListLogLogPlot[tab, Joined -> True]
```

[image]